# Grails 2.0.4 Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing Springloaded

Tags: java, spring, grails, spring-loaded

I've just downloaded Grails 2.0.4 and extracted it to /opt/grails/grails-2.0.4/ and made sure that the GRAILS_HOME environment variable is correct. But whenever I try run the "grails" command, I get the following error:

```
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : /opt/grails/grails-2.0.4/lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.2.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I don't understand what the problem could be. I've been using Grails-2.0.1 for months successfully in exactly the same way on exactly the same machine. I've tried re-downloading the grails-2.0.4.zip file in the hopes that it was a problem with the archive, but that didn't help. I also copied springloaded-core-1.0.2.jar from the grails-2.0.1/ directory, but that just caused another set of errors.

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like your PATH has not been updated correctly. In other words, you are running the 2.0.1 grails script with GRAILS_HOME set to 2.0.4. You can tell because the version of spring loaded reported in the error message - 1.0.2 - is not the one required by Grails 2.0.4 (to help others diagnose this issue).

Comment: Thanks, I just restarted my bash session and the PATH problems disappeared. Thanks for help in understanding the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I experienced this error too. The problem is spaces in the grails home path.

If it's this:

```
c:/grails 2.1.0/grails2.1.0
```

Then it will give an error, as there's a space between "grails" and "2.1.0". I just removed the spaces and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you cleared out the **.grails** folder in your home directory?

Grails caches a bunch of files in there, it could be that that is tripping you up.

I have had similar problems in the past when my internet connection wasn't a 100% reliable, it seems that the Grails downloader does not do thorough checking of downloaded files, so files in cache can become corrupt.

Answer (score 1):

*It's the folder hierarchy problem!*

I have faced the same issue : when i set Grails_home make sure the path you are giving is e.g `c:/grails2.1.0` and not `c:/grails2.1.0/grails2.1.0`

it often happens when you unzip the folder 2 folder with same name are created one inside another.

hope this will resolve!!!

Answer (score 0):

**I had the same problem. Here is how I solved it:**

*Previously*:
I had grails in: `C:\Program Files\grails-2.5.5`
and in the system's environmental variables I had
GRAILS_HOME: `C:\Program Files\grails-2.5.5`  and also
`C:\Program Files\grails-2.5.5\bin` in PATH.

*Then I tried*:
To put grails in `C:\Grails_2.5.5\grails-2.5.5`
and updated GRAILS_HOME to `C:\Grails_2.5.5\grails-2.5.5` and the text in PATH to `C:\Grails_2.5.5\grails-2.5.5\bin`
BUT, I still got the same error.

***What fixed it:***

1. Put grails in C: `C:\grails_2.5.5`
2. Update Environmental variables to the correct grails path:
   -GRAILS_HOME: `C:\grails-2.5.5`

   -In PATH: `C:\grails-2.5.5\bin`
3. Restart pc

*Wish you luck!*