# Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/Program

Tags: java, grails

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\ubiquibacon>set

GRAILS_HOME=C:\Program Files\GGTS\grails-2.0.4
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
Path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25\bin;C:\Program Files\GGTS\grails-2.0.4\bin

C:\Users\ubiquibacon>grails
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:/Program
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
C:\Users\ubiquibacon>
```

I have two main Grails project I work with.  Project "A" is in production is developed with Grails 2.0.4 using Netbeans, project "B" is still a prototype and is developed with Grails 2.2.4 using [GGTS](http://grails.org/products/ggts).  I have a `.bat` script I run to quickly change my `GRAILS_HOME` and `PATH` variables when switching between the two versions of Grails.  This worked well until I decided to play around and open project "A" in GGTS.  I also recently upgraded Java from 1.6.0_18 x86 to 1.7.0_25 x64.  Now something is preventing Grails 2.0.4 from running at all as can be seen from the posted command line output.  My environment variables and path are correct, I have deleted the `.grails` directory, and I have restarted my computer, none of which have helped correct the problem.

The first line of the error is curious because it appears to be looking in a non-existent path `C:\Program`.  I wonder if the rest of the path may be getting hacked off because of a space `C:\Program Files\???` but that is just a thought.

I have already tried all the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145814/grails-2-0-4-error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-springloaded) question, none of which helped solve my issue.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

**Update:**

A work around listed in the JIRA issue [here](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-7936) says to change line 60 of `startGrails.bat` from this:

```
set AGENT_STRING=-javaagent:%GRAILS_HOME:\=/%/lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.5.jar -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails
```

to this:

```
set AGENT_STRING="-javaagent:%GRAILS_HOME:\=/%/lib/com.springsource.springloaded/springloaded-core/jars/springloaded-core-1.0.5.jar" -noverify -Dspringloaded=profile=grails
```

After doing that I get a new error:

```
C:\Users\westerhold>grails


Exception: java.lang.NumberFormatException thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "main"
C:\Users\westerhold>
```

Comment: It is quite unfortunate that GVM is only available for UNIX/LINUX so Grails installation is slightly harder on Windows. Maybe it is time to try Linux for development :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but when I use the older version of Java I don't have any issue.  I don't know if it is because my older version of Java was Java 6 instead of Java 7, or because my older version of Java was 32 bit instead of 64 bit, but setting my `JAVA_HOME` variable to point to the older version of Java when using Grails 2.0.4 seems to be working.

Answer (score 5):

Obviously the error cause is spaces in the path. Try to reinstall `Grails` by the path without spaces.

Comment: The spaces were part of the problem.  Installing Grails to a path without spaces was necessary (for Grails 2.0.4) unless I did the work around I mentioned in my question, but even with spaces removed the error persisted.  The problem didn't go away until I changed `JAVA_HOME` to the 32 bit Java 6 install path.

Comment: you have solve my problem but can you tell me why was this happening ?

Answer (score 3):

While giving path in environment variable there should not be space,this is wrong 
C:\Programs Files\grails-2.3.4 so the solution is giving path like with no space
C:\Programs\grails-2.3.4

Hope it help :)

Comment: In my case, I needed to add a trailing slash in the GRAILS_HOME variable for some reason