# grails-2.4.3 not working?

Tags: grails, groovy

I just downloaded grails 2.4.3 and created a test application, but it fails when trying to run the application.

Anybody knows why its going wrong here?

Thanks

```
C:\workspace\grails_apps\testApp>grails run-app

| Running Grails application
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : C:\Program%20Files%20(x86)\Grails\grails-2.4.3\lib\org.springframework\springloaded\jars\springloaded-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error

C:\workspace\grails_apps\testApp>
```

Comment: grails run-app --stacktrace try stacktrace for more information

Comment: please check, if the mentioned file is ok.  if not usually deleting it and doing a `grails package` should fix this.

Comment: check the path, this may be the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/11145814/217324

Comment: Thanks, path looks ok, grails package did not make any difference, grails run-app does not give any further details.. still no luck.

Comment: have you checked the jar?

Comment: Tried grails clean-all ? http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/clean-all.html

Comment: grails clean-all didn't solve the issue. I am also facing the same issue with the grails 2.4.4 snapshot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Upgrading grails from 2.1.1 to 2.4.3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25950549/upgrading-grails-from-2-1-1-to-2-4-3)

Answer (score 2):

For anyone interested,

this problem was solved by moving the grails installation from

C:\Program Files (x86)\Grails\grails-2.4.3

to

C:\Grails\grails-2.4.3

eg. by **removing the spaces in the GRAILS_HOME path** as explained in the post found [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145814/grails-2-0-4-error-opening-zip-file-or-jar-manifest-missing-springloaded).

Note, it did not work to remove the spaces by setting GROOVY_HOME = C:\PROGRA~2\Grails\grails-2.4.3